# How to write a file to Android SD Card that is visible on PC

Tags: java, android, eclipse, file-io

I am trying to store data in a file while my application is running in order to easily get it off of the device when I connect it to a PC.

Right now, I am able to create the file and write to it, but my computer cannot see the file.

Note that I would really prefer not to use DDMS as I will be asking people with limited experience to do this.

I know it is writing the file, as I can see it on the device's file manager. If I copy the file into another directory on the device, I can then see it on a computer, but this isn't a valid workaround for my situation.

Here is what I have:

```
String fileName = "test";
String stuffToWrite = "testString";
try
{

  File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
  File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath());
  dir.mkdirs();
  File file = new File(dir, fileName + ".csv");

  file.setReadable(true,false);


  FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

  OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 

  // Write the string to the file
  osw.write(stuffToWrite);

  /* ensure that everything is
   * really written out and close */
  osw.flush();
  osw.close();
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This may not help, but when I was writing images to the "Pictures" directory I had to disconnect the device from the computer and reconnect before I could see them through the file directory.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It doesn't seem to be working in my situation unfortunately, but I will keep that in mind for the future. Thanks!

Comment: With the devices which export their external storage as a "USB Mass Storage Device" (typical of Android 2.x) you **cannot** access the external storage from both the phone and the computer at the same time.  Instead, they take turns - the phone looses access while the storage is mounted to the PC.  The newer MTP scheme eliminates that problem, at the cost of others.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/46315/not-all-files-are-visible-over-mtp

Answer (score 0):

Try to add file.createNewFile();

```
File file = new File(dir, fileName + ".csv");
file.createNewFile();
```

Comment: The file is created, however it is not visible by Windows on the SDCard. I can only see it through the file manager on the device.

Answer (score 0):

The following example will create a file in the Android external storage root directory called "hello.txt":

```
package external.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class WriteExStorage extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String ex_storage_directory;

        ex_storage_directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

        File f = new File(ex_storage_directory, "hello.txt");

        try
        {
          PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(f));

          p.println("Hello External Storage!");
          p.close();
        }
        catch(java.io.IOException e)
        {
          return;
        }
    }
```

The call to getExternalStorageDirectory() will fail if the external storage device is not available. See [getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) for details.